# Trapezoid Rule to Simpson's Rule Extrapolation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, extrapolation

I need to show that one extrapolation of the trapezoid rule leads to Simpson's rule.

I've looked through the other posts on ME, specifically [the post with the same title](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382190/simpsons-rule-derived-from-trapezoidal-rule), [and this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113667/relation-between-simpsons-rule-trapezoid-rule-and-midpoint-rule?rq=1) for help, but I still don't have a clear idea of how to answer this.

I understand that the extrapolation from $n$ subintervals to $2n$ subintervals reduces the error term, and helps the formula converge faster.

Can anyone help direct me toward a constructed argument? I'm not seeing how to directly make the inference.

Comment: Which part of the post is confusing you?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the actual process of starting with the trapezoid rule, performing an explicit extrapolation step, and having the result be something resembling Simpson's rule. I understand that they're in the same "family", but what is the direct correlating step that shows this to be the case.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, Simpson's method can be obtained by applying Richardson's extrapolation to the trapezoidal method. We begin with the trapezoidal method: 
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \approx  \frac{h}{2} \left\{   f(x_0)+ 2f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+2f(x_3)+\dots \\ \dots  
+2f(x_{n-1}) + f(x_n) \right\}\tag{1}$$
where $h=(b-a)/n$ and $x_i=a+ih$. The error of trapezoidal method is known to be of order $h^2$. Therefore, if we double $n$, thus halving $h$, the error should go down by about the factor of $4$. We can then subtract $1/4$ of the original formula (1) from the new one, thus canceling out the error term with $h^2$. The result is Simpson's formula, and this is the derivation you are likely to see in a textbook.

But I find it notationally easier to proceed in the opposite direction: using  $h$ and $2h$, not $h$ and $h/2$.
To this end: let $n$ in the formula (1) be  even. Next, write down the trapezoidal rule with step $2h$. It will involve only $x_0,x_2,x_4,\dots,x_n$:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \approx  h \left\{   f(x_0)+ 2f(x_2)+2f(x_4)+2f(x_6)+  \dots  \\ \dots +2f(x_{n-2}) + f(x_n) \right\}\tag{2}$$
The error of formula (2) is about $4$ times the error in formula (1), since we doubled the step size. 
So we divide both sides of (2) by $4$ and subtract the result from (1), hoping to cancel out the error.
$$\frac34 \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \approx 
\frac{h}{2} \left\{   f(x_0)+ 2f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+2f(x_3)+\dots \\ \dots 
+2f(x_{n-1}) + f(x_n) \right\} \\ -  \frac{h}{4}\left\{   f(x_0)+ 2f(x_2)+2f(x_4)+2f(x_6)+\dots \\ \dots
+2f(x_{n-2}) + f(x_n) \right\}  $$
Collect like terms:
$$\frac34 \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \approx 
\frac{h}{4} \left\{   f(x_0)+ 4f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+4f(x_3)+\dots \\ \dots
+4f(x_{n-1}) + f(x_n) \right\}   $$
Finally, multiply both sides by $\frac43$ and you'll get Simpson's formula.