# Simpson's Rule like Method for Arc Length Approximation

Tags: calculus, differential

Simpson's Rule is of course a very important method for Numerical Integration.  The basic idea behind it is to the intervals as a quadratic curve, and to calculate the area under that curve (yes, I realize I'm simplifying it:  I don't think I need to go over the details).

What I'm curious is, if I want to Numerically calculate the arc length of a function over a given interval, is there a similar trick we can use to calculate it?  I'm aware of the basic method behind calculating arclength 
$\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt(dt^2 + (f(i + 1)-f(i))^2) $
, but can't find anything helpful similar to the Simpson's rule.

Also, the only function we can use are those from the original function.
So for instance, if I want to find
$Arc Length = \sqrt(x) $ from x = 0 to 100, the only functions we can use values from is $f(x) = \sqrt(x) $

I bring this up because I've seen several sites that just say to use Simpson's Rule Integration with
$ \int_0^{100} \sqrt(1+ [f'(x)]^2)dx $
but that is NOT what I am referring to (that's cheating :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10867651.2001.10487548#.U2MRhqE9mY4)?

Comment: Awesome, that look's great!

Answer (score 4):

Simpson's Rule is the result of Richardson's extrapolation applied to trapezoidal rule, [as seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777487/). So, we can obtain its natural analog for the arclength by applying the same extrapolation to the sum-of-chordarcs formula. It goes like this:

Let $n$ be an even integer. Take the sum of chords over $n$ chords:
$$L \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{(x_{i }-x_{i-1})^2 + (f(x_{i })-f(x_{i-1}))^2 } \tag{1}$$
where $x_i = a+i (b-a)/n$, $i=0,\dots,n$. Then do the same for $n/2$ chords:
$$L \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \sqrt{(x_{2i}-x_{2i-2})^2 + (f(x_{2i})-f(x_{2i-2}))^2 } \tag{2}$$
Since the sum-of-chords formula has error of order $1/n^2$ (error comes from second derivative of $f$), the error in (2) should be about $4$ times the error in (1). So, divide (2) by $4$ and subtract it from (1). Result: 
$$  L \approx \frac43 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{(x_{i }-x_{i-1})^2 + (f(x_{i })-f(x_{i-1}))^2 } \\ - 
\frac13 \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \sqrt{(x_{2i}-x_{2i-2})^2 + (f(x_{2i})-f(x_{2i-2}))^2 }  \tag{3}$$
This improves precision in the same manner as Simpson's rule improves over trapezoidal method.

---

**Example**: The length of parabola $y=x^2$ between $(0,0)$ and $(10,100)$; the same graph as in your post, turned sideways. Using $n=100$ in (1),
I get within $8.3\cdot 10^{-4}$ of the exact length. Using the same $n=100$ in (3), I get 
within $10^{-9}$ of the exact length.
Huge improvement, with no extra evaluations of $f$ (the second sum in (3) uses the values of $f$ already found for the first sum). It appears that (3) is of 4th order of accuracy when $f$ is smooth, just as Simpson's rule.

The improvement is far less spectacular for $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,100]$, which is not smooth at $0$. This interval calls for an adaptive method, because on most of it the function is almost flat but near $0$ its derivative blows up. This is true for both area and length computations. To make (3) adaptive, subdivide $[a,b]$ recursively, stopping 
when the results of (1) and (2) are sufficiently close to each other. Apply (3) on each subinterval you obtained, and sum the result.

---

The algorithm proposed by   [Vincent  and Forsey](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10867651.2001.10487548), pointed out by Biswajit Banerjee in a comment, is likely to outperform (3) - after all,  they spent time thinking about particulars of length computation, while (3) is a straightforward extrapolation of sum-of-chords formula.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I implented your method and Vincent and Forsey's (without the recursive features) in C++ to compare them and got some shocking results.  They were damn near identical, i.e. 100.99757783592801 & 100.99757783592796 for 100 intervals and 100.80088559028958 & 100.80088559028957 for 10 intervals.  It appears they're the same methods approached from two different angles.

Comment: @Mandalf, after reading [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2005.10.001) it can be seen that the two methods have about the same order of convergence, which matches your observations.

Comment: I thought I was so clever when I offhandedly said 'there must be an arc-length analog for Simpson's rule'. It took digging to find this, but brilliant. Well done.