# What is the relationship between $M(f)$, $I(f)$ and $T(f)$ where M is the midpoint rule and T is the trapezoid rule?

Tags: integration, solution-verification, error-function, numerical-calculus

> It is necessary to approximate
>
> $$I(f) = \int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ where f is a function that has $2$ continuous
> derivatives. If $M(f)$ and $T(f)$ are the approximations obtained
> through the Midpoint Rule and the Trapezoid Rule, respectively, and
> $f''$ is constant, what is the relationship between $M(f),T(f)$ and
> $I(f)$?

I did this

$$|E_T|= \frac{k(b-a)^3}{12h^2} \\
|E_M| = \frac{k(b-a)^3}{24h^2} \\
\frac{|E_T|}{|E_M|} = 2 \\
|E_I| = 0$$

The relationship is $|E_I| < |E_M| < |E_T|$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be beginning to analyze estimates of the *potential errors* in the uses of $M(f)$ and $T(f)$ as opposed to the estimates themselves.

You may be expected to notice that "$f''(x)$ is constant" (quite a hypothesis!) means that $f(x)$ is a quadratic function, for which the "Simpsons Rule" approximation, although it is not expressly mentioned here but you may have heard of, will be exact (i.e. "$S(f)$," the Simpsons approximation, will be $I(f)$).

And there is a well known linear relationship between the midpoint, trapezoid, and Simpsons approximation methods that is described below:

[Relation between Simpson's Rule, Trapezoid Rule and Midpoint Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113667/relation-between-simpsons-rule-trapezoid-rule-and-midpoint-rule)

Note that the problem does not provide what number of partitions (or which partitions) are being used to evaluate the rules. The answer linked above (and simplicity of $f$) may shed light on that.